# How to get variables between the curly brackets in django template in django views?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I have django template file. Now i want to get all the variables list that are between curly brackets. I think it is possible with the regular expressions. And i read about regular expressions. But there is no function i found to be helpful.

template code snippet:

```
           <tr><td>
                Dear Candidate,<br/>
                Welcome to Creative Talent Management!<br/>
                We have created an account for you. Here are your details:<br/>
                Name:{{name}}<br/>
                Email:{{email}}<br/>
                Organization:{{organization}}<br/>
                Password:{{password}}<br/>
            </td></tr>
```

I want to get ***name,email,organization,password*** in my python function.

Right now i'm reading the template but getting empty list.

```
if created:
        temp_path = str(instance.html_template.path)

        html_file = open(instance.html_template.path, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
        file_data = html_file.read()
        render_param = re.findall("^{{ . }}$", file_data) 
        print("html param ",render_param)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's sort of back-to-front. You would normally pass all the variables which *might* be used from your view to the template rendering through the context. It doesn't matter if  one or more of the context variables are unused by the template. Of course, you should have a test which catches variable name spelling errors (`{{usernmae}}` will render as null string without error ).

For checking the template, you might simply `grep '{{' some_template.html`, or write something in Python to get (say) an alphabetically sorted list of variable names. But that's a program-development aid, not a part of the Django server code.

If you *really* wanted to, you could just open the template file and write similar Python code as part of your view. But, why??

Comment: I'm trying to open html template file. but i'm getting error. i have updated question. Please check

Comment: Why not just open `instance.html_template`? Anyway, the file isn't where you think it is. Maybe use `find / -iname email_test_template_gBC7WVP.html -ls` to track it down?

Comment: Or maybe it's a temp file that's been deleted by the time you are trying to open it?

Comment: the file is still there. And i tried `instance.html_template` way but error occurs that says path should be string , you passed an object.

Comment: Find out what sort of object it is (`print(type(instance.html_template))`) and then the source code should reveal where the name of the file is stored. If the source code is hard to come by, reverse-engineering from `print(dir(instance.html_object))` may be a possible hack.